# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with dynamic columns

Tags: mysql

I have a tab-delimited text file with this format:

```
Vehicle     Car     Mazda    Atenza     2009    Grey
Vehicle     Car     Honda    Fit        2007
```

The first two fields are constant, while the rest of the fields can be dynamic - there can be any number of them.

Is there a way with the MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` command to import this data into a database table, given the dynamic number of fields?

Comment: While there can be any number of them, if present, are they reliably in the same order?  I don't think LOAD DATA INFILE can handle this, but you may be able to preprocess the file with `awk` for example.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski They will all be reliably in the same order.

Comment: Then you can simply create all the possible fields in the right order then and LOAD DATA into it.